# How to find the parameter transformation between two stereo graphic projection

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

On the sphere: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, there are two stereo graphic projection(from North and South respectively):

$$x=\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1},y=\frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1},z=\frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1}$$

and
$$x=\frac{2\widetilde{u}}{\widetilde{u}^2+\widetilde{v}^2+1},y=\frac{2\widetilde{v}}{\widetilde{u}^2+\widetilde{v}^2+1},z=\frac{1-\widetilde{u}^2-\widetilde{v}^2}{\widetilde{u}^2+\widetilde{v}^2+1}$$

How to find the parameter transformation between $u,v$ and $\widetilde{u},\widetilde{v}$ in their public domain?(the whole sphere minus North point and South point). Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a figure showing a meridian half-plane through $N$ and $S$, and you shall see that the two points $(u,v)$ and $(\tilde u,\tilde v)$  coming from the same point $(x,y,z)$ on the unit sphere are related by a reflection on the unit circle. Therefore one has
$$\tilde u={u\over u^2+v^2},\quad \tilde v={v\over u^2+v^2}\ .$$
[image]

Comment: elegant proof, beautiful figure

Answer (score 1):

Put $r=u^2+v^2$ and $\widetilde{r}=\widetilde{u}^2+\widetilde{v}^2.$ Then equating the two $z$ coordinates gives $\widetilde{r}=1/r$, and after that equating the $x$ and $y$ coordinates gives $\widetilde{u}=u/r,\ \widetilde{v}=v/r.$

Note: at first this seemed odd since I thought $|u/r| \le 1$, which would restrict the value of $|\widetilde{u}|$. But for small $u,v$ the value $|u/r|=|u/(u^2+v^2)|$ is not bounded, so it looks OK in that respect.